# php Array storing key from a foreach loop into string

Tags: php

I have a key-pair array like this

```
$option['33']="Steak Doness";
$option['34']="Size";
$option['35']="Cooking Method";
```

I want to store the keys into a string like this

```
$key="33,34,35,";
```

I try to use foreach loop

```
$key="";

foreach($option as $key => $value) {
    $key=$key.",";
}
echo $key;
```

However, my output is

```
35,
```

May i know which part went wrong?

Comment: just try `echo $key = implode(",", array_keys($option))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss use the `$key` in your script.

**The problem is with the `$key` which is in the foreach loop...**. In each time your `$key` variable updated with the loop... Try with difference variable in your script.

OR, simply use

```
echo $key = implode(",", array_keys($option));
```

Comment: Technically `echo $key = implode(",", array_keys($option)).',';` if you want to produce the exact output OP is showing.

Answer (score 0):

1st change your varible $key to $keys 
replace one line

`$key=$key.",";`

to

`$keys .= $key . ",";`

it will work 100%

Comment: what is the logic of these?? If i add the key each time and store in the same variable then is there anything wrong?? **The problem is with the `$key` which is in the foreach loop...

Comment: you are re-assigning  `$key` every time but you need to concat it so :)

Comment: You misunderstood, Just take a look.. there are 2 `$key`, One is in the foreach loop and another is to store the keys..

Comment: your coding its not working. plz check. Frayne's one is working

Comment: @FrayneKonok used `implode` function that will produce output like 33,34,35 not like 33,34,35,

Comment: I think @gosulove is a programmer and he knows to add a `,` after the keys if he need and I make two choice...